# Determine who unfriended me on Facebook

Tags: facebook, friends

Is there a way to find out who "unfriended" me on Facebook?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for an applicaiton!

Comment: I constantly recieve spam for applications that supposedly do that.

Comment: Just be weary of the service you choose to track this.  On a similar note there are many that claim they will show you "who is blocking me?" on MSN - they request your credentials to login, then spam your entire address book.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Intentionally, Facebook prevents sending out this info for privacy purposes.  You are free to keep track of your friends though in some other form, and compare it to the current list to find out who is missing each week.

[who.removed.me](http://who.removed.me) will do this for you automatically

Comment: Should be combined with http://ifttt.com/ to create a notification service whenever someone removes you.

Comment: @Michael Pryor Are you sure that friends who unfriended you disappear from your "Friends List"? I noticed that one person's status updates stopped appearing on my news feed long time ago, but when checked "Friends List" he is still there.

Comment: @Boris_yo There are many different ways to manage privacy settings on Facebook. That person could still be your friend but may not be using Facebook, or might have said they don't want their updates appearing on your feed, or the algorithm that decides what to show you (it doesn't show all things) decided not to show you that person's updates.

Answer (score 11):

Sites like [who.removed.me](http://who.removed.me/) will keep track of your friends list and compare it automatically.

Comment: +1 for the site.  I added it to my answer and referenced you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep a log of who has added you as a friend is to enable email notifications. Then [create a filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/what-subjects-lines-do-facebook-notification-emails-contain) so it doesn't clog your email inbox.

It wouldn't really be practical comparing all these email messages to your friend list, especially if you have hundreds of them, but if you want to check if you were ever friends with someone, you could just search your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing friends, somehow you won’t be able to tell the difference between a deactivation and a de-friending.

Comment: You could see if there is still a facebook account for that user. If so then it is a defreinding, otherwise it was just a deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

If using Firefox the Greasemonkey plugin has scripts that will allow you to see this information right on the Facebook dashboard.  The script I use is: [Better Facebook](http://userscripts.org./scripts/show/61761)

Comment: this app no longer has the unfriend tracker, they had to remove it due to pressure from facebook

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that: "Who Unfriended Me?"!

It compares an old list of your friends with a current list of your friends, so that it can show you who unfriended you!

Check http://apps.facebook.com/whounfriendedme/

Answer (score 0):

The **[Who.deleted.me](http://who.deleted.me/)** app will allow you to see friends who have unfriended you (or have deactivated their accounts). [FAQ link here](http://who.deleted.me/?FAQ). It can show this list by day, week, month or in graph form.

[image: Who.deleted.me]

---

Also, the [**Unfriend Notify**](http://www.fbfriendcheck.com/) browser extension for Firefox and Chrome can show a pop-up notification when someone unfriends you on Facebook. It also adds a new tab section for "Lost Friends" in the [Friends page](http://www.facebook.com/me/friends), which will list people who have unfriended you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for finding out who unfriended you is the [FB Purity](http://fbpurity.com) browser extension. It also has a built in deleted friends notification system, that alerts you if any of your friends remove you from their friends list.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://truefbfriends.com—It will tell you who are your real Facebook friends and who are fake Facebook friends. It will also give you data like how many likes, comments, mutual friends and chats your friends have done with you. It will also tell who removed you. A perfect website to filter your friends on the basis of interactions.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose that in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is an application on Facebook called [Who deleted me ?](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=121138571299822&sk=info).
It has 1.9 out of 5 based on 15 reviews. On installing the application you are met with page which will tell you who are your removed contacts. On further inspection, the associated [page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Who-deleted-me-/120544111353967) does seem to have positive reviews.