# How can I filter out Facebook notification emails?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I'm trying to create a filter on my Facebook email so that notifications are labeled as one category, while other account-related messages are labeled something else. The problem is that they both come from `facebookmail.com`.

Is there a list of common phrases that occur in the subject so I can create a rule to filter these messages out? Any other ways to filter out these messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some account-related subjects (and the *from* address):

- Facebook Contact Email Change Notification (`notification+*@facebookmail.com`)
- Facebook Contact Email Confirmation (`notification+*@facebookmail.com`)
- Please reset your email notification settings (`root+*@facebookmail.com`)

#### Using `subject:`

> from:(facebookmail.com)
>   subject:(-"suggested you" -"sent you a
>   message" -"invited you to" -"confirmed
>   you as a friend" -"wants to be
>   friends" -"commented on" -"added you
>   as" -"replied to a thread" -"wrote on
>   your wall" -"shared a link" -"tagged"
>   -"listed you as" -"made a comment about" -"poked you on" -"replied to
>   your post" -"sent you a gift" -"added
>   a friend" -"posted on your wall")

#### Using `from:`

> from:(facebookmail.com)
>   -from:(notification OR eventmaster OR groupmaster OR confirm OR notes OR
>   wallmaster OR video OR photos OR
>   giftmaster)

Notice, however, that this will also match the two account-related notification emails from above.

Answer (score -1):

I would look for the following: change, you, notification, about, and request.   This should eliminate 95% of all notifications based on my experience