# How to disable Facebook email notifications?

Tags: facebook

Facebook sends me a lot of notifications on my email and sometimes it annoys me. How can I disable all these notifications? I just want to check the incoming messages only when I open Facebook website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Account** (top right) > **Account Settings** > **Notifications**.
2. **Uncheck** all the **notifications** you don't want.
   If you have a lot of them that you want to uncheck, you could use a [Toggle Checkbox bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html#toggle_checkboxes).
3. Press **Save Changes** at the bottom.

Note that it says at the bottom:

> Even if you turn off all
>   notifications, we may sometimes need
>   to email you important notices about
>   your account

You can also create a filter in your email client which [filters out notification email only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/what-subjects-lines-do-facebook-notification-emails-contain).