# How do I get my Facebook notifications settings back?

Tags: facebook, configuration

I recently started receiving facebook notification emails despite having configured against it.
I first thought it was a temporary fluke and went to check my settings (Account settings as answered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/how-to-disable-facebook-email-notifications)), only to find that the notifications settings tab was gone.
I have tried logging out from all clients and logging back in. Also tried different browsers, but it's just not there.

Does anyone know how to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked my account and there's still a "Notifications" tab. It's URL is

> http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?notifications

Answer (score 0):

[According to Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14504), this can be caused by the Facebook application on your mobile phone.